# specifying a date/time format with timezone

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to display sysdate in the following format?

```
Wed Oct 16 15:04:44 MDT 2013
```

This comes out of unix date format.

```
echo `date`
```

EDIT: the latest version is missing timezone information. Also, I am not sure if this is the most elegant solution :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'DY') || ' ' || to_char(sysdate, 'MON DD') || ' ' ||     to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MM:SS' ) || ' ' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY' )  
FROM DUAL ;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

Comment: you don't need to `echo \`date\``, you can just say `date`, right? Good luck.

Comment: i am trying to replicate how unix displays the date/time. if i simply do echo date, then it outputs date.

Comment: @David Aldridge , please see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

`sysdate` returns value of `date` data type, which does not contain information about timezone. To be able to display abbreviated version of timezone region you need to operate on values of timestamp with time zone data types and use `TZD` format element in a date time format mask:

```
select to_char( cast(sysdate as timestamp with local time zone)
              , 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZD yyyy') as res
 from dual
```

Result:

```
RES                           
-------------------------------
Thu Oct 17 02:14:00 PDT 2013
```

---

**Edit**

> Wed Oct 16:12:0 2013 is what i got

Try to explicitly specify exact time zone region for a session. Because there are might be several time zone regions associated with one offset and oracle wont be able to choose one and returns null. So before executing the query execute `alter session set time_zone='<<specify_exact_time_zone_region>>'`. For example:

```
SQL> alter session set time_zone='Canada/Mountain';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_char( cast(sysdate as timestamp with local time zone)
  2                    , 'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZD yyyy') as res
  3       from dual;

RES                                                                             
-------------------------------                                                 
Thu Oct 17 02:51:14 MDT 2013
```

Comment: Wed Oct 16:12:0  2013     is what i got.

Comment: If you use SYSTIMESTAMP instead of SYSDATE then you get the date, time, and timezone of the system. Might be a better approach.